# Summary Across Reports - MS Access 2013

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I try to build report in ms access 2013 and i need to calculate sum rows of column if another row in other column is 1 but it always give me the sum of all column what i should do?

```
 [code] IIf([action_type]=1,Sum([net]),0) [code]
```

Answer (score 0):

From my experience the Sum function doesn't seem to work in the middle of the of the IIF statement. Try:

```
Sum(IIf([action_type]=1,[net],0)
```